# Pandas Import error after installation in Wing IDE

Tags: python, pandas, importerror, python-import

I am having some major problems importing Pandas and it is driving me crazy.
I installed Pandas from terminal using

```
pip install pandas
```

as well as all dependencies.

Now when I try to import pandas I get

```
ImportError: No module named pandas
```

This is true in terminal and in Wing.

I have tried changing python path but I am not really sure how to do that. I am a Stats guy not really a developer. My goal ideally is to have Wing point to the python where pandas is located but also to be able to access pandas in terminal as well:

```
Mac / usr / local / lib / python2.7 / site-packages / Pandas
```

When asking in terminal

```
which python >>> /usr/bin/python
```

Which is running python 2.7.6 and the pandas package is sitting in my python2.7 folder, so I don't know why it's not recognizing it.

Is this a quick fix or a deeper issue in the way I installed pandas, Wing, and python?

Comment: what about `which pip`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two different Pythons in your system: Apple's default one in:

```
/usr/bin/python
```

and one in:

```
/usr/local/bin/
```

If you run:

```
/usr/local/bin/python34
```

you will be able to import the packages installed with pip34:

```
pip34 install pandas
```

If you want to permanently use the new Python, then make an alias or change the search order in our `PATH` env variable so that `/usr/local/bin/` is searched before `/usr/bin`.

Comment: -bash: /usr/local/bin/python: No such file or directory

Comment: When I run that it doesn't work, but /usr/local/bin contains pip, pip2, pip2.7, pip3, pip3.4, and python3, python3.4

Comment: then try, `/usr/local/bin/python3`

Comment: /usr/local/bin/python3    then   import pandas results in the same error. Pandas is in the python2.7 site packages, and my terminal /usr/bin/python uses 2.7, I don't really understand the problem.

Comment: oh you are right, the idea is to run the same python as the pip you install pandas with, for example try: `pip3.4 install pandas`, and then `/usr/local/bin/python34`

Comment: Ok so that works, but how would I change the python path to python 3.4 in Wing?

Comment: Ok, then I will edit the answer with the solution. Please don't forget to mark it as accepted if it helped. Regarding the WingIDE issue you should post a new question for that. May be somebody who uses WingIDE will be able to help.